# Numeric output from program not as expected

Tags: java, arrays

The code looks correct but it does not work like I expect it would:

> Sample Run1:
>   Fill array of 5 elements with binary? (1-yes, 0- no): 1
>   Array generated: 0 1 1 0 0
>   Sample Run2:
>   Fill array of 5 elements with binary? (1-yes, 0- no): 0
>   Array generated: 9 8 8 2 1

The code:

```
public static boolean Q1(int a) {
    if (a == 1)
        return true;

    return false;    
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Fill array of 5 elements with binary? (1-yes, 0- no): ");
        int num = s.nextInt();
        int[] Array1 = new int[5];
        if ( Q1(num) == true){
            for ( int i = 0; i<5 ; i++){
                int ran = 0 + (int) Math.random() + (2);
                Array1[i] = ran;
                System.out.print(Array1[i] + " ");

            }

        }
        else 
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i<5 ; i++){
                int ran = 0 + (int) Math.random() + 10;
                Array1[i] = ran;
                System.out.print(Array1[i] + " ");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

NOT : Suppose the user only enters 1 & 0*

I get this output:

> Fill array of 5 elements with binary? (1-yes, 0- no): 0
>   10 10 10 10 10

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
(int) Math.random() + 10;
```

which just returns 10 always since Math.random() returns 0 to 0.999999, and casting to int returns 0 always.

to

```
(int) (10 * Math.random());
```

which returns 0 to 9

The other would be

```
(int) (2 * Math.random());
```

which returns 0 or 1.

---

A better option would be to use a Random object and call `nextInt(2)` on it for binary or `nextInt(10)` for the non-binary int.

Comment: What's the meaning of "hovercraft full of eels"? :D

Comment: @AayKay: most important, do you see why your code does not work?

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun: it's from a Monty Python comedy skit.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  : Yess it wasn't generating random numbers, it was just generating the last number

Comment: @AayKay No. It was generating only 10 because it's casting [0,1) to `int`, which is always 0, and adding 10..

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun oh okaii , now i got it ! Thanks Maroun !